# Blackberry: Kill an application

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to kill an running application in blackberry, just like as task manager. Is there is any way to do that or any API available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this method to kill a UiApplication....

```
public void killApp() {
      System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes. If an app freezes, doesn't shut down correctly, or runs away eating up resources, being able to kill it manually should be an essential feature of any OS API.

Comment: yes i want to kill other running application.......some times it happens that application does not respond or it is stuck that time i need to kill an application

Answer (score 0):

As per other forums, below are the information I found. Try this if it helps you

**First Way:** you might have to just do a hard boot. take the battery out if all fails.

**Second Way:**

```
Stop a job that is running

 1. In the BlackBerry® Administration Service, on the Devices menu, expand Deployment jobs.
 2. Click Manage deployment jobs.
 3. Search for the job that you want to stop.
 4. In the search results, click the ID of the job that you want to stop. You can only stop jobs with a Running status.
 5. Click Stop Current Execution.
 6. Click Yes - Stop Current Execution.
```

[Stopping a job that is running](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/16661/Stopping_a_job_564541_11.jsp)

Comment: If you figure it out, let me know.  I want to kill the native webbrowser all the time, it never exits fully and takes up WAY too much memory.  I use other browsers, but sometimes they do not render or behave as well as the native browser (memory usage aside).

Comment: Probably because it doesn't really address the original question.