# Foreground App Close with Process ID: Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Want to close the third party application which are only in **foreground**  by its processID not the super apps. Is there is any API to do that.

There is a way you can kill your app by   *System.exit(0);*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You asked this question [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684670/blackberry-kill-an-application). There is no api to kill another application from your app.

Comment: I asked it for both foreground and background application...but now i need to close only foreground application by its processID...

Comment: There is no api to close another application from your application. Background/foreground - it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. API's provide you with control to your application only not to other apps. You can invoke another application but you cannot control it, exit or request background and foreground to it.